# My payment for developer account is failed in play store. I used International debit card of hdfc

Tags: google-play

I used different international debit cards, but its always showing
"Your request failed. Ensure your payment method info is correct or add a new payment method to your Google Account. Learn more [OR-CCSEH-05]".
I tried to pay by entering card info's to google play console while creating developer account.

Comment: Does the card support online transactions without VbV or 3D Secure? Usually, the implementation is through an SMS/email token for each transaction, which Google Play doesn't support.

Comment: I am not very much in this area, I just need to pay 25 dollars to google play to create my developer account. thanks @Martheen,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The card address and your address should be the same, this error result from different country on the card than your location.

- Change your [google payments address](https://pay.google.com/payments/home#addressBook) to your card country.
- Try the [How to change your Google Play country](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en).
- Or contact Google Play Support for more help.

Comment: i tried all of the methods still the issue is there